# How to add files in docker container volume on build time

Tags: docker, dockerfile, volume

I have a python and java app that I want to run inside a container.
I have a folder named `pass-hash` with:
--`h2o-start` folder containing `Dockerfile` that I use to start `h2o.jar`which starts a server for machine learning.
--`model-generator` folder containing `passhash.py` and a `data.csv` file.
The `passhash.py` app contains `h2o.import_file("/var/my-data/data.csv")` which takes the `data.csv` file from the `my-data` folder I created in the container and generates a POJO file with it.
The `h2o-start Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD h2o.jar h2o.jar
EXPOSE 54321
EXPOSE 54322
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "h2o.jar"]
```

The `model-generator Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM python:2.7-slim 
WORKDIR /model-generator 
ADD . /model-generator 
RUN mkdir /var/my-data 
COPY data.csv /var/my-data 
RUN chmod 777 /var/my-data/data.csv 
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt 
EXPOSE 8080 
ENV NAME World 
CMD ["python", "passhash.py"]
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file contains:

```
version: "3"

services:

   h2o-start:
    image: milanpanic2/h2o-start
    build: 
      context: ./h2o-start
    ports: 
      - "54321:54321"
      - "54322:54322"
    volumes:
      - "home/data"

   model-generator:
    image: milanpanic2/model-generator
    build:
      context: ./model-generator
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "h2o-start"
    volumes:
      - "csvdata:/var/my-data" 

volumes:
 csvdata:
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the use case. Volumes give you persistence, overwriting the image contents with that of the volume, often from a prior run of the container. If you want to inject the data into your build, do you need the volume at all?

Comment: I am a little confused about it too. I suggest to edit and add all compose.yml, and dockerfile, and detail use case explaination to question again, really not easy to read it in comments.

Comment: I don't know, that is the solution i came up with. Can you tell me the better solution for my problem? My problem is: I have a python app that uses  a `data.csv` file to generate a `POJO machine learning model`. When I specify a path to this python app to the data file, it gives an exception that the file doen't exist. Also, I have another app written in java, that uses the generated POJO file and it gives predictions based on that data. The java app also updates the `data.csv` file every day. I want every app (microservice) to run in separate container, but want them both to use the data.csv

Comment: I will edit it now, with everything

Comment: Your problem is you first copy csv to `/var/my-data`, the use volume `- "csvdata:/var/my-data"`, the content in `/var/my-data` was override by named volume `csvdata` in host again. So you could not see csv data. You do not need to copy csv to container, just map the host folder(with csv) to container as a volume, and 2 containers share the host folder to utilize the csv data is enough for you. @Rohan J Mohite's new answer could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know, that is the solution i came up with. Can you tell me the better solution for my problem? My problem is: I have a python app that uses a data.csv file to generate a POJO machine learning model. When I specify a path to this python app to the data file, it gives an exception that the file doen't exist. Also, I have another app written in java, that uses the generated POJO file and it gives predictions based on that data. The java app also updates the data.csv file every day. I want every app (microservice) to run in separate container, but want them both to use the data.csv

To answer this, You need to use volumes.

Try below code.

This is your docker-compose file

```
version: "3" 
services: 
  h2o-start: 
  image: milanpanic2/h2o-start 
  build: context: ./h2o-start 
  ports: 
    - "54321:54321" - "54322:54322" 
  volumes: 
    - /home/data:/var/my-data 
model-generator: 
 image: milanpanic2/model-generator 
 build: context: ./model-generator 
 ports: 
  - "8080:8080" 
 depends_on: 
  - "h2o-start" 
 volumes: 
  - /home/data:/var/my-data
```

This is your docker file

```
FROM python:2.7-slim 
WORKDIR /model-generator 
ADD . /model-generator 
RUN mkdir /var/my-data
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "passhash.py"]
```

And where is your java docker file?

Now just create a default data.csv file and copy it in your host machine location /home/data.

and run application let me know.

Comment: `ERROR: for pass-hash_h2o-start_1  Cannot create container for service h2o-start: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\home\\\\data:/var/my-data"\nis not a valid Windows path'

ERROR: for h2o-start  Cannot create container for service h2o-start: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\home\\\\data:/var/my-data"\nis not a valid Windows path'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`
it gives this error

Comment: are you using windows? I did ask this question before.

Comment: yes, my local machine is on windows, but in the container it's linux

Comment: Then just replace \home\data with actual windows machine location (C:\inetpub\). the error state that is not valid windows path

Comment: Good, Next time please try to provide all information in one :) Best luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Docker Volumes are designed to share folder in between Host Machine and Docker containers. If you copy any file on your host machine (volume location path), it will be automatically going to available inside containers.

The syntax for docker volume is as below:

```
 -v /home/data:/data
```

In the above syntax **/home/data** is folder available on the host machine and **/data** this folder is available inside docker container.

If you copy any file on the host machine inside **/home/data** folder, it will be automatically going to be available inside container **/data** folder.

Hope this is clear to you.

If you are using docker-compose then add volume tag as below

```
 volumes:
   - /home/data:/data
```

for example:

```
version '3'
 services:
  app:
   image: nginx:alpine
     ports:
     - 80:80
   volumes:
    - /home/data:/data
```

Comment: Where do i write `-v /home/data:/data` in the Dockerfile ?

Comment: But then it's now on build time.

Comment: But that's fine, just keep whatever files you want on host machine location /home/data and then just run docker run with -v flag, after successfully running all files will be available inside container.

Comment: I don't understand, can you write the full thing. I want to call docker-compose file. I configured it so it will call the respective Dockerfiles. Now I want the Dockerfile to take the data.csv file and put it in the volume.

Comment: For docker-compose, look at above code or still struggling then share your docker-compose file.

Comment: `version: "3"

services:

   h2o-start:
    image: milanpanic2/h2o-start
    build: 
      context: ./h2o-start
    ports: 
      - "54321:54321"
      - "54322:54322"
    volumes:
      - "csvdata"

   model-generator:
    image: milanpanic2/model-generator
    build:
      context: ./model-generator
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "h2o-start"
    volumes:
      - "csvdata:/var/my-data" 

volumes:
 csvdata:`
that is my docker-compose

Comment: your host machine is Ubuntu? in both container h2o-start and model-generator you need  csvdata file?

Comment: Just replace your volume tag as  volumes: - /home/data:/var/my-data   keep your csv file inside hostmachine /home/data/ folder, and it will be available in /var/my-data folder. make sure you are creating my-data folder in you docker file.

Comment: `FROM python:2.7-slim
WORKDIR /model-generator
ADD . /model-generator
COPY data.csv /var/my-data
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "passhash.py"]`
that is the model-generator Dockerfile

Comment: See mounting volume and copy file inside container both are different things, if you just want to copy CSV file inside docker-container then you need to create folder  RUN mkdir /var/my-data and then use COPY data.csv /var/my-data. Hopefully, data.csv file is placed near to docker file.  Don't make any changes in docker-compose and try.

Comment: also you need to provide run & write permission to csv file as RUN chmod 777 /var/my-data/data.csv

Comment: here is your updated  docker file   FROM python:2.7-slim 
 WORKDIR /model-generator 
 ADD . /model-generator 
 RUN mkdir /var/my-data
 COPY data.csv /var/my-data 
 RUN chmod 777 /var/my-data/data.csv
 RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt EXPOSE 8080 ENV NAME World CMD ["python", "passhash.py"]

Comment: Error: File /var/my-data/data.csv does not exist. I get this exception

Answer (score 1):

If you mean add files when do docker build, take a look at [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) & [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) instructions.

Comment: this is my docker-compose.yml file
`version: "3"
services:
   h2o-start:
    image: milanpanic2/h2o-start
    build: 
      context: ./h2o-start
    ports: 
      - "54321:54321"
      - "54322:54322"
    volumes:
      - "csvdata"
   model-generator:
    image: milanpanic2/model-generator
    build:
      context: ./model-generator
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "h2o-start"
    volumes:
      - "csvdata:/var/my-data" 
volumes:
 csvdata:`

Comment: and my model-generator Dockerfile:
`FROM python:2.7-slim
WORKDIR /model-generator
ADD . /model-generator
COPY data.csv /var/lib/docker/volumes/pass-hash_csvdata/
VOLUME /test-data
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "passhash.py"]`

Comment: I can't see it in the volume and I tried both with add and copy

Comment: So, what you really want? Put data.csv to image, and finally you want to see it which place? Any detail path? From what you currently: you can just see data.csv in /var/lib/docker/volumes/pass-hash_csvdata/ in container I think. Named volume for host filesystem I think, so seems a little chaos for your afforded thing.

Comment: I want to see the `data.csv` in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/pass-hash_csvdata/` and I want to use it in my app that is in container, but it's not working for some reason.

Comment: I'm doing it this way, because I will have another app append this file.

Comment: When you say `another app append this file`, the app means model-generator container? Then seems just `COPY data.csv /var/lib/docker/volumes/pass-hash_csvdata/` line has meaning, other part of your code meanless. Then there should one folder `/var/lib/docker/volumes/pass-hash_csvdata/` in container model-generator. If not, it is really strange, and I think I still did not catch your point why you need to write so many things, and why need volume? As from your explaination, you just want to put data.csv to container, the app in container use it, none business of volume.